# How to stop server(node) in Apache Ignite using c# .net

Tags: c#, ignite

i'm created simple c# application with

var ignite = Ignition.Start();

And also ignite instance with next operation performed not executing.

There is way to stop node in c#.net after stop application because in topology on console after stop and start application again show with one increment server.And also heap memory taking 3.4 GB per server.

please tell me about ignite any configuration to achieve same.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop ignite instance (`IIgnite`) in two ways:

- `Ignition.Stop(ignite);`
- `ignite.Dispose();`